# Bootstrap 5's Button Text is Black Instead of White Like their Demo

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I am not sure if this is something I did wrong when installing Bootstrap 5, but a lot of my buttons are using a black font instead of the white font as is seen on the [Bootstrap 5 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/)

For example, the `.btn-primary` on the Bootstrap docs looks like this:

[image: primary button with white text]

However when I use the identical HTML I get this as a result:

[image: primary button with black text]

For reference the HTML in both their example and mine is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Not only is the text colour a different colour, but the background colour is different as well. In fact looking through my compiled .css file, a good chunk of the bootstrap colours used all across the code has this "washed out" appearance similar to the blue colour in the button.  From the Chrome dev tools the style appears to be coming from Bootstrap files themselves, not from any style I am inadvertently applying. The SCSS is being compiled down to CSS files via the normal Laravel setup (webpack mix). I am just using the NPM packages for bootstrap 5.

`window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');` and NPM package `"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",`

My app.scss file doesn't have much at all in it:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons";

// "Lobster" Font for H1's
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cuprum&family=Lobster&display=swap";

// Flatpickr Styles
@import "~flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css";

// Font Awesome Free
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";

// DataTables Styles
@import "~datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css";
@import "~datatables.net-responsive-bs5/css/responsive.bootstrap5.min.css";

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

a.torn-link {
    color: $orange;
}

.ttt-title {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
.card-title {
    font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
}
html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #636b6f;
}
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #636b6f;
}
.links {
    >a {
        color: #636b6f;
        padding: 0 25px;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: .1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}
#settings-button {
    &:hover {
        fill: rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.25);
    }
}
.ui-dialog-title {
    font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
}

thead, th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Edit:** Even all the Bootstrap Colored links appear to be washed out. For example the `.link-warning` yellow is not possible to use as the colour is too washed out to be able to read it. Whereas the yellow on their page is completely readable. So it's not even that I am just accidentally applying a style to a button or something.

Edit2:

Here is what my button looks like in the dev tools (note the colours differ from what the Bootstrap 5 docs colours have

[image: dev tools my button chrome]

and the buttons CSS is just coming from the compiled app.css file generated via the webpack:

[image: bootstrap css]

Edit 3: My `_variables.scss` file:

```
// Body
$body-bg: #f8fafc;

// Typography
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 0.9rem;
$line-height-base: 1.6;

// Colors
$blue: #3490dc;
$indigo: #6574cd;
$purple: #9561e2;
$pink: #f66d9b;
$red: #e3342f;
$orange: #f6993f;
$yellow: #ffed4a;
$green: #38c172;
$teal: #4dc0b5;
$cyan: #6cb2eb;
```

Comment: Could you inspect the button in the browser and see where the button colour, or buttons' text colour is coming from?

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali I added a couple pics related to the dev tools. It's just coming from my generated `app.css` file so it doesn't indicate very much. And as an added note, if I scroll up a bunch, these CSS properties are in fact coming from the Bootstrap stylesheet. It's being compiled into the `app.css` file. It seems like something when it is compiling is generating this colour from the Bootstrap files and I don't know why.

Comment: Check your variables file for `--bs-*` variables.

Comment: Seems like a very weird problem, but yeah as the above comment suggests, open your `_variables.scss`, and check the color assigned to `$blue` for starters.

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali Yeah that seems like where the issue lies. I see colour variables in here. This file was automatically created when I installed bootstrap via NPM so I have no idea why these colours were added into the scss file. I guess bootstrap already have built in colours set so I assume I am safe to just remove all the colours listed in here?

Comment: Removing those colours did indeed fix the issue. No idea where those colours came from. I assumed those were supposed to be there. Well feel free to submit an answer mentioning the solution and I will mark it as solved :)

Comment: I am glad you solved it, though how it happened remains a mystery. But given you solved it yourself, you should post the solution and accept that as the answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `_variables.scss` file at some point in adding Bootstrap 5 to Laravel 8 it looks like one of the scripts added colours, or I messed up at some point and added a colour pallet into the variables file.

All of the colours in the variables file were similar to the Bootstrap default colours, but instead were a more washed out version. This is what was causing anything in Bootstrap which used these variables to appear washed out.

Simply removing all the colours I had defined in the `_variables.scss` file fixed the problem.

Comment: But removing color in _variables.scss is going to remove custom color i have added for my theme

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer ComputerLocus, I was experiencing the same problem. Since I couldn't add a comment due to reputation I will write this answer.

The solution stated was correct. In more detail you need to accesss `_variables.scss` which can be found in `resources/sass/`. Once you delete the conflicting declared colours, you will need to run `npm run dev` in the terminal inside your main project directory. If changes still not showing, refresh your page using `ctrl + F5`.

That's all, folks :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 features a [Color Contrast](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#color-contrast) function. This code snippet is used throughout Bootstrap to ensure components meet the [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/) color contrast accessibility guidelines. When you create a `.btn-primary` component, Bootstrap runs your `$primary`/`$blue` hex value through the color contrast function and checks its relative lumanance. In this instance, `#3490dc` does not have sufficient contrast with the default `color: #FFFFFF` text styling for the button, so it switches it to `color: #000000` instead.